# I need help making a variable for the character in Lua from a script in StarterGUI

Tags: lua, roblox

```
sneakCheck.Touched:Connect(function()
    if sneak == false then
        --what do I put in here 
    end
end)
```

i want to check if the character is sneaking when  the sneakCheck is hit and if its false he will die how do i create a valuable for him so i can easily reference him

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Make your sneak animation or function or whatever that will determine its value
local sneak = false

-- Check if the object that it hit is a player (because it is triggered by anything that it hits)
sneakCheck.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") and hit.Parent.Humanoid.Health > 0 and sneak == false then
        -- Kill the user
        hit.Parent.Humanoid.Health = 0
    end
end)
```

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: and does this work in a localscript whos parent is starter GUI but thank you so much cottient

Comment: No this has to be in a script. You can have it in workspace under the sneakcheck trigger.